# Grafana max and min threshold with base in between

Tags: grafana

I have Grafana 9.2 and want to draw a TimeSeries with 2 thresholds: below and above allowed numbers so that Green Base is in between.

Example of [visualisation](https://community.grafana.com/t/threshhold-lines/31301) I'd like.

The problem is that 'Base' is always below each of the Threshold and have no idea how to move that in between. Is there any option?